# Datetime Formatting giving it a specific culture doesn't change how day is printed out

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is DateTime format strictly dependent on the language of the OS being used? Because the following doesn't work:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var usCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dddd MM-dd-yy"),usCultureInfo);
```

I'd like the result to print out as **Saturday, 06-29-2013** but the day gets printed out in Korean **토요일, 06-29-2013**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a victim of [Composite Formatting overload for Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf.aspx) where you could pass Format string and a series of object to be inserted in the placeholders of the format string

You need to write in this way

```
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dddd MM-dd-yy",usCultureInfo));
```

and you get the right day text.

See the specs here [DateTime.ToString(format, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx)

Comment: Wow.. pretty dumb mistake by me.. I meant to put the culture inside tostring but I gave it as an argument of writeline.. thanks

Comment: Yes a side effect of Composite Formatting on WriteLine

Answer (score 0):

Or simply you can use

```
string abc=date.ToString("dddd MM-dd-yy");
```